# PyCharm code completion and dynamic casting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting, code-completion

I'm pretty new to Python 3 and type-hints and I'm wondering if it's possible to do this in PyCharm or other IDE's.

## Example

Here's a simplified example of the code.

```
import dataclasses
from typing import Type

@dataclasses.dataclass()
class BasePlugin:
    version: str
    arguments: str = None

@dataclasses.dataclass()
class PythonPlugin(BasePlugin):
    version: str = 3.7
    script: str = None

@dataclasses.dataclass()
class MayaPlugin(BasePlugin):
    version: str = 2022
    scene_file: str = None
    script_job: str = None


class Job:
    def __init__(self, plugin: Type[BasePlugin]):
        self.options = plugin()


job_a = Job(plugin=PythonPlugin)
```

Ideally, I want to be able to create an instance of `Job` and use dot-notation to modify the `options` fields.
e.g. `job_a.options.script = 'c:\test\do_stuff.py'`

## Problem

##### Incorrect result

With the input type-hint, code completion only shows the available attributes of the base class.

Code sample:

```
class Job:
    def __init__(self, plugin: Type[BasePlugin]):
        self.options = plugin()


job_a = Job(plugin=PythonPlugin)
job_a.options.
```

Result: [Code completion with input type-hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq0w4.png)

---

##### Incorrect result

Without the type-hint, code completion shows nothing, as expected.

Code sample:

```
class Job:
    def __init__(self, plugin):
        self.options = plugin()


job_a = Job(plugin=PythonPlugin)
job_a.options.
```

Result: [Code completion without input type-hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSSXm.png)

---

##### Desired result

What I want is the code completion for the specific subclass I'm providing on instantiation.
In the example below, I'm overriding `self.options` with the plugin to show the desired result.

Code sample:

```
class Job:
    def __init__(self, plugin: Type[BasePlugin]):
        self.options = PythonPlugin()  # Overriding to simulate the desired result.


job_a = Job(plugin=PythonPlugin)
job_a.options.
```

Result: [Code completion as desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ayh6K.png)

## Solutions

1. Is it possible to achieve the desired result by passing in an argument?
2. If not, is my only other option to subclass the job types?

```
class Job:
    options: BasePlugin
    ...

class PythonJob(Job):
    options: PythonPlugin = PythonPlugin()
    ...

class MayaJob(Job):
    options: MayaPlugin = MayaPlugin()
    ...
```

3. Any other options/examples I need to consider?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with TypeVars and Generics:

```py
import dataclasses
from typing import Generic, Type, TypeVar

BP = TypeVar("BP")

@dataclasses.dataclass()
class BasePlugin:
    version: str
    arguments: str = None

@dataclasses.dataclass()
class PythonPlugin(BasePlugin):
    version: str = 3.7
    script: str = None

@dataclasses.dataclass()
class MayaPlugin(BasePlugin):
    version: str = 2022
    scene_file: str = None
    script_job: str = None


class Job(Generic[BP]):
    def __init__(self, plugin: Type[BP]):
        self.options: BP = plugin()


job_a = Job(plugin=PythonPlugin)
job_a.options.script  # auto-completes

job_b = Job(plugin=MayaPlugin)
job_b.options.scene_file  # auto-completes
```

Comment: I have moved on, but this is still incredibly useful information for me.
Tested and it works exactly as I needed.

Thank you so much!